# qBittorrent on-screen notifications (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: 15.10, notification, qbittorrent

Once upon a time there were the qBittorrent on-screen notifications that told everyone that their download was complete. Then came Ubuntu 15.10, which destroyed them all.

Is there a way to restore them? I've already checked the box *Display program on-screen notifications* in *Options->Advanced*, but they seem to be gone, forever.